# How to get the previous row value with an ORDERING BY DATE?

Tags: sql-server

When I run the here below code I get this error :

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 14 Operand type clash: int is
>   incompatible with date

Here below my code for which I get the here above error:

```
declare @tbl table (
cat1 nvarchar(500),
cat2 nvarchar(500),
someDate date
);

insert into @tbl values
('A','B','2016-01-01'),
('A','B','2016-01-02'),
('A','B','2016-01-03'),
('A','B','2016-01-04'),
('A','B','2016-01-05');

select 
cat1,
cat2,
someDate,
LAG(someDate,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY cat1, cat2 ORDER BY someDate asc) as PreviousSomeDate
from @tbl;
```

And here below the expected result (the previous row value of [someDate]) :

```
('A','B','2016-01-01',''),
('A','B','2016-01-02','2016-01-01'),
('A','B','2016-01-03','2016-01-02'),
('A','B','2016-01-04','2016-01-03'),
('A','B','2016-01-05','2016-01-04');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAG(someDate,1,0)` means: return the previous value of the column `someDate` and if there is no "previous" column (because it's the first row) return the value `0`.

If that *was* possible, you would have a integer value in that column for the first row and a date value for all other rows. All values of one column **must** have the same data type, so SQL Server complains, that "*int is incompatible with date*"

You need to use a date as the default value (the third parameter). You apparently don't want any value, so just use `lag(someDate)` which will return `NULL` for the first row.